# In computer science is there a word for the fact that all data representations are equal?

Tags: computer-science

For programming languages, we have the concept of Turing completeness which expresses the fact that all computers and all languages are equal in their ability to represent any algorithm so long as we ignore the capacity of the storage medium. Is there a similar word for data encodings/representations?

For example, any number can be represented in unary, binary, ternary form. So long as all the data structures have the same "data capacity" between any given 2 structures A and B there exist functions:

```
to :: A → B
from :: B → A
```

Where `from ∘ to == id`.

This is obviously true for any (context insensitive) data structure that exists in a computer because they are literally all just strings of bits. But what is the word for this?

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better suited on [cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen it turns out that I should post this to cs.se not cstheory. cstheory is for grad level questions ;) https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/material-to-supplement-the-faq/2662#2662 thanks though.

Comment: I didn't even know about "cs.", thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, I think you mean to refer to Turing-equivalence, not Turing-completeness, which is something similar but not identical. As for your question: I don't think there's a general term for it, other than perhaps to say that two encodings are *equivalent*. If you have a particular encoding you'd like to use as the standard, e.g. *decimal* for encoding numbers, you'd be understood if you said that binary is a *decimal-equivalent* system for encoding numbers.

Of course if you mean that two systems are equivalent not just semantically (they can encode the same things) but also syntactically (their encodings work essentially the same way) you can use terms like isomorphic (meaning that each string in one encoding maps to one string in the other encoding, and vice versa).